# spring boot jasypt encrypts but not able to decrypt, throws EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I am using spring boot jasypt 3.0.3, jasypt-1.9.3 cli.

encryption

```
encrypt.bat input="shri" password=U0RELU1USS1Db3Vwb24tU2VydmljZQ== algorithm=PBEWITHMD5ANDDES saltGeneratorClassName=org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator providerName=SunJCE ivGeneratorClassName=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator stringOutputType=base64
```

decryption

```
decrypt.bat input="MStQnSmJV13y7DAfL+7/JA==" password=U0RELU1USS1Db3Vwb24tU2VydmljZQ== algorithm=PBEWITHMD5ANDDES saltGeneratorClassName=org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator providerName=SunJCE ivGeneratorClassName=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator stringOutputType=base64
```

Spring boot API

```
package com.example.demo;
import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;
import org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimpleStringPBEConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class DemoApplication {
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "U0RELU1USS1Db3Vwb24tU2VydmljZQ==";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "PBEWITHMD5ANDDES";
    private static final String ITERATION = "1000";
    private static final String POOL_SIZE = "1";
    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "SunJCE";
    private static final String SALT_CLASS = "org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator";
    private static final String IV = "org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator";
    private static final String OUTPUT_TYPE = "base64";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static StringEncryptor jasyptStringEncryptor() {
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
        config.setPassword(SECRET_KEY);
        config.setAlgorithm(ALGORITHM);
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations(ITERATION);
        config.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        config.setProviderName(PROVIDER_NAME);
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName(SALT_CLASS);
        config.setIvGeneratorClassName(IV);
        config.setStringOutputType(OUTPUT_TYPE);
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return encryptor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

controller

```
package com.example.demo.controller;
import org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jasypt")
class SpringBootController {

    @Autowired
    StringEncryptor stringEncryptor;


    @Value("${my.secret}")
    private String pass;

    //working 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewPass")
    public String viewPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    //working 
    @GetMapping(value = "/jasyptEncode")
    public String jasyptEncode(@RequestParam String plainText) {
        System.out.println("jasyptEncode receives request parameters as ===" + plainText);
        String newpass = stringEncryptor.encrypt(plainText);
        return newpass;
    }
    //not working 
    @PostMapping(value = "/jasyptDecode")
    public String jasyptDecode(@RequestBody String param) {
        System.out.println("param = " + param);
        String realpass = stringEncryptor.decrypt(param);
        System.out.println(realpass);
        return  realpass ;
    }
}
```

applications. properties - using CLI generated encrypted password

```
my.secret=ENC(MStQnSmJV13y7DAfL+7/JA==)
```

build .gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.1.0-m3"
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '16'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am able to decrypt applications.properties password which is generated by CLI using spring boot API but at the time of passing the same password and decryption using API, it's saying EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException.

logs

```
2021-07-31 22:09:36.079 DEBUG 16072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
2021-07-31 22:09:36.201 ERROR 16072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException] with root cause

org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: null
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1169) ~[jasypt-1.9.3.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:738) ~[jasypt-1.9.3.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:511) ~[jasypt-1.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.SpringBootController.jasyptDecode(PrintPassInYmlController.java:34) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

**what ab am I missing?**

Answer (score 0):

got it
for anyone facing the same issue.
I was sending the password in query param and hence was getting alteredd.
took it in a class and it worked.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import lombok.Data;
import org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jasypt")
class SpringBootController {

    @Autowired
    StringEncryptor stringEncryptor;


    @Value("${my.secret}")
    private String pass;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewPass")
    public String viewPass() {
        return pass;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/jasyptEncode")
    public String jasyptEncode(@RequestParam String plainText) {
        System.out.println("jasyptEncode receives request parameters as ===" + plainText);
        String newpass = stringEncryptor.encrypt(plainText);
        return newpass;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/jasyptDecode")
    public String jasyptDecode(@RequestBody Temp temp) {
        System.out.println("param = " + temp.getPass());
        String realpass = stringEncryptor.decrypt(temp.getPass());
        System.out.println(realpass);
        return realpass;
    }
}

@Data
class Temp implements Serializable {
    private String pass;
}
```